# sorted array with three different integers with only one pass

Tags: c++, c

is there possible way to sort an array of three integers with only one pass on the array?

you get:

```
int array[]={1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3}
```

and you are told that there are only number 1,2,3

to get:

```
int array[]={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3}
```

and no extra space allowed

Tnx!

Comment: Count the number of occurrences of each number, then generate the list from that.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? How did it work? How didn't it work? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay That only takes a single pass.

Comment: @user3660832 See my answer. There is a ready to use solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One pass with no extra space:

> first pointer: Denotes start of 2 in the array.
>
> last Pointer: Denotes start of 3 in the array.
>
> If you find a 1, swap it with the first pointer.
>
> If you find a 2, keep it there.
>
> If you find a 3, swap it with the last pointer.

Dry run:

```
{1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3} cur=1, first=1, last=10
{1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3} cur=2, first=2, last=10
{1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3} cur=3, first=2, last=10
{1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3} cur=4, first=2, last=10
{1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3} cur=5, first=2, last=10
{1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3} cur=5, first=2, last=9
{1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3} cur=5, first=3, last=9
{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3} cur=6, first=4, last=9
{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3} ...
```

Time: O(n) (one pass)

Space: O(1)

Comment: How did you set the two pointer and three pointer without looping through the array two additional times?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The pointers are just plain incremented or decremented. No looping.

Comment: I understand that. How were they set in the first place? Like I have program, it has an array. Now where did those two pointers come from? Also, don't pointers take space?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think by no extra space it is meant that space is constant. Otherwise no program would be possible without extra space.

Comment: Is an int[3] more then constant space now?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, if the size of the array be 1 million, the 3 would remain a 3.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay Yes pointers are allowed. ** {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3} cur=5, first=2, last=9** how does 3, know to go before the other three?

Comment: @user3660832 If 2 was in the end, just one swap is required. Try out with a pen and paper and it'll be clear.

Comment: @AlexanderGessler Yes, thanks. I don't understand why the question is downvoted so much. Also someone in the comments got so many upvotes by  saying something even without properly reading the question.

Comment: I've upvoted it, however I think it got downvoted because the question was not very clearly formulated, and required some clarification which so far is only found in comments. OP should consider editing the question to include that (i.e. that no extra space means O(1)).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Basically, you walk the input array once and count for each of the values how often they occur. Afterwards, you just emit the appropriate number of values for each bucket.

Edit: counting, not bucket sort.

Comment: thank you!! but i forgot to add that there is no extra space allowed

Comment: As in, no extra variables can be declared? In that case, I don't think an algorithm that satisfies all the constraints exists.

Comment: Usually, with this question in an interview context you are allowed O(1) extra space. If the number of distinct values is known a-priori it is a constant, and the extra space required to hold the counters is O(1). You're sure _no_ extra storage is allowed?

Comment: Algorithms such as this are time-space trade offs. If you cannot allocate additional space, then the amount of time must increase.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: For example, can he declare a variable to know what position in the array he is in? That's normally part of the `O(1)` extra space.

Comment: Yes, no extra spcae allowed. A hint i got told me its soemthing with partition algorithem

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward approach (without testing)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void sort( int *first, int *last )
{
    for ( int *current = first; current != last; )
    {
        if ( *current == 1 )
        {
            if ( current == first )
            {
                ++current;
            }
            else
            {
                std::swap( *current, *first );
            }
            ++first;
        }
        if ( *current == 3 )
        {
            --last;
            if ( *current != *last ) std::swap( *current, *last );
        }
        if ( *current == 2 ) ++current;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) with a simple linear solution  described by E. W. Dijkstra in the early 70's. It's sometimes used as a partitioning method for quicksort.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename BidIt, typename T>
void dnf_partition(BidIt first, BidIt last, const T &pivot)
{
    for (BidIt next = first; next != last;) {
        if (*next < pivot) {
            std::iter_swap(first++, next++);
        } else if (pivot < *next) {
            std::iter_swap(next, --last);
        } else {
            ++next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };

    for (int n : array) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    dnf_partition(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 2);

    for (int n : array) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/rIlTEE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With a counting sort,

```
int array[]={1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3};
int count[]={0,0,0};
int i = 0;
while (array[i] != '\0') {
  count[array[i] - 1]++;
  i++;
}
for (i = 0; i < count[0]; i++) {
  printf("%i", 1);
  printf(",");
}
for (i = 0; i < count[1]; i++) {
  printf("%i", 2);
  printf(",");
}
for (i = 0; i < count[2]; i++) {
  printf("%i", 3);
  if (i + 1 < count[2]) {
    printf(",");
  }
}
printf("\n");
```

**Edit**

> With no extra space allowed.

Then no. It's not possible.

Comment: What if the input array is `int array[]={100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,300,300}`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen The initial problem statement said 1,2,3. For 100, 200, 300 you could have a 300 element array. Or you could do some other radix sort.

Comment: As long as you know there are only 3 integers, you can just map each one to 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch With the current approach you would be wasting `297*sizeof(element)` memory with a 300 element array.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I actually gave an implementation of counting sort. It still only loops through the initial array once. By the way, a binary radix sort usually uses 254 elements (since one byte can't be that large).

Comment: @user3660832 Sorry. No extra space? Then no, it's not possible.